# Installing R 3.5.2 on Mac OS Mojave - error with libcurl version during ./configure -

Tags: r, macos, curl, installation, libcurl

I'm trying to update my version of [r](/questions/tagged/r) from `3.5.1` to `3.5.2` ("eggshell igloo").  Following the instructions in the INSTALL file that came with the package found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/), I went to the package directory and ran `./configure`.  After many minutes, I received this error:

> checking if libcurl is version 7 and >= 7.22.0... no configure: error:
>   libcurl >= 7.22.0 library and headers are required with support for
>   https

I cannot seem to figure out what exactly is broken here, and what steps I'll need to take to fix it.

Comment: Why don't you use the binary installer provided? Then you wouldn't need to bother with this.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  How do I do this?  Where does it describe how to do this?

Comment: Follow the link you provide, download `R-3.5.2.pkg`, double click the file, proceed as usual when installing a program on Mac OS. You don't give a reason why you'd need to install from source, which is what the instructions in `INSTALL` refer to.

Comment: It sounds like there's something super obvious to you that constitutes "proceed as usual," but in this context I do not know what you are referring to.  When I double-click `R-3.5.2.pkg` file it opens a directory with a lot of smaller files in it, including the `README` and `INSTALL`, the instructions from which I am trying to follow.  Is this wrong?

Comment: Additionally, what's the difference between installing from source, as opposed to "proceeding as usual?"  And if installing from source throws errors, why can I trust "proceeding as usual" to work correctly?

Comment: Something is broken on your system. Double clicking the file should open [the installer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installer_(macOS)), which would guide you through installation. Maybe ask there how to fix this: https://apple.stackexchange.com